# How can I scale the PVC of a statefulset?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

When I try to edit the PVC, Kubernetes gives error saying:

> The StatefulSet "es-data" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: updates to
>   statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', and
>   'updateStrategy' are forbidden.

I am trying to increase the disk size of elasticsearch which is deployed as a statefulset on AKS.

Comment: Could you please mention kubernetes version you're on?

Comment: @PrafullLadha I am using Kubernetes 1.11

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explaining. You can only update `template` and `updateStrategy` part of a StatefulSet. Also, you can't resize a PVC. However, from kubernetes 1.11 you can resize pvc but it is still alpha feature.

Ref: [Resizing an in-use PersistentVolumeClaim](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#resizing-an-in-use-persistentvolumeclaim)

> Note: Alpha features are not enabled by default and you have to enable manually while creating the cluster.

Comment: I get that. Also, I have enabled Alpha features on my cluster. What I need to achieve is to scale the disk allocated to my elasticsearch cluster. I can go ahead and edit the PVC one by one (I have 3 node elasticsearch), but will it get reflected in elasticsearch configuration? Also, If I had to kill the pods of elasticsearch after increasing the PVC manually, won't elasticsearch request a PVC with the size which was set while deploying it?

Comment: Hmm.. that could be. You should try in test  environment first. You can create pvc separately rather than volumeClaimTemplate. Then it won't have this problem. You can check this guide aobut resizing pvc https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to expand the PVC of a statefulset on AKS, following these four steps:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71175193/4083568